# PC will not turn on sometimes just Green light will be ON

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, desktop-computer

I have a weird problem in my desktop. I have been using it for more than one year. Problem occurs from last week.

Sometimes when I try to turn on my pc when I press the ON button just the green light alone will be glowing and red light will never come. Nothing will happen after that. I waited for ten minutes still it is the same.

Also this happens 2 out of 5 times not always.. Also same problem sometimes occurs even the system is switched ON.. When I leave the computer turned ON for 15mins or so without using it.. Consider listening to songs suddenly after 15mins or so system will go blank and song will stop just green light will be glowing in CPU

**Note :** I turned OFF hibernate and sleep still no use

Workaround is :
If I switch off my power supply and turn it on immediately then it will restart and work.. This could spoil my hardware.. Can somebody help me on this..

Comment: The same problem here for me too. When I turn it on, the green light will glow and fan will start it's work. But it won't boot. Then when I switch off the power supply and turn it on again, It will work.

Comment: I have a similar situation. When the computer is in sleep mode, sometimes when I want to wake it up, it just power off and I have to push the power button to turn it on again. Obviously at this moment the computer is then doing a full boot.

Comment: Borrow a new psu to test. I've had this issue.  Before hand make sure all connectors from psu are well connected

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cant comment so I try to answer here somehow:

Cant it be that your power supply is failing?

When you can switch it on, go to bios and search for voltages. Is 12V is nearby 12V and not for example 13V or 11V, and other voltages also are good, then its not necessarily that problem.

If you have possibility, try with other power supply.

In my understanding, a power supply might "warn" you before failing completely.